# Struggling when appending dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking forward to append various dataframes through a loop that extracts from a web a series of data. The function `ratios_funda` by its own works correctly, however I don't find a way to loop it according to the different tickers and append them one after the other in the empty `dataframe`. Here is the code.

```
import pandas as pd

cartera = ['FB.O', 'SAN.MC','TRE.MC', 'BBVA.MC']

def ratios_funda(x):
    rat1=x[2].loc[[1,7,8,10],:]
    rat2=x[3].loc[[1,5],:]
    rat3=x[5].loc[[1,2,4,5],:]
    rat5=x[7].loc[[5,6],:]
    rat6=x[8].loc[[1,7],:]

    rats=[rat1,rat2,rat3,rat5,rat6]
    df=pd.concat([df.set_index(df.columns[0]) for df in rats])
    df.index.names=['Fundam ratios']
    df.rename(columns={1:'Company',2:'Industry',3:'Sector'}, inplace=True)
    df.index = df.index.str.strip()

    return df

def resultados():
    dataframe=pd.DataFrame()
    for titulos in cartera:

        ruta=pd.read_html('http://www.reuters.com/finance/ 
        stocks/financialHighlights?symbol='+str(titulos),flavor='html5lib')
        if dataframe.empty:
            dataframe= ratios_funda(ruta)
        else:
            dataframe=pd.concat([dataframe, ratios_funda(ruta)],axis=1)
    return dataframe

print(resultados())
```

It looks like it does not loop.

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: the problem I am finding is in trying to  loop the first function with the different `ruta` and append them one after the other one in `dataframe`. By the way thank you for the edition LanS

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance. Do you get an error message?

Comment: I don't get an error in the code, the problem is that I would like in the function`resultados` to append the results from the first function, which it doesn't does. I believe I am doing wrongly the loop.

Comment: As you can see in the list `cartera` there are 4 tickers. I want the results `ratios_funda` appended one after the other for the 4 tickers.

Comment: I don't know why @User193452 removed their suggestion, but yes your `return dataframe` is improperly indented.

Comment: can you try adding index and define your cartera as dataframe :'

    cartera = pd.DataFrame(index=['1','2','3','4'], columns=['FB.O', 'SAN.MC','TRE.MC', 'BBVA.MC'])

and put the `return dataframe`, outside of the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is with having `return` in the `for` loop.

```
def resultados():
    dataframe=pd.DataFrame()
    for titulos in cartera:
       ruta=pd.read_html('your url here')
       if dataframe.empty:
          dataframe= ratios_funda(ruta)
       else:
          dataframe=pd.concat([dataframe, ratios_funda(ruta)],axis=0)
    return dataframe
```

Answer (score 0):

It was not a problem of the code, the issue was that not all tickers were structured the same way in the HTML and that is why I had mixed results. Thanks everyone for your help!